# Groovy easy way to mock HTTP request

Tags: groovy, spock

I have very simple connector to connect to rest API:

```
class ApiConnector {
   def url

   ApiConnector(url) {
      this.url = url
  }

  def get(enpointName) {
    "$url/$endpointName".toUrl().text
  }
}
```

And my problem is that I want to have unit tests for the get method with some mocked outputs. I want to do this with Spock but don't know how actually can I approach this. Any help?

Answer (score 2):

What's wrong with plain meta-programming?

```
URL.class.metaClass.getText = { 'test text' }

'test text' == "http://stackoverflow.com".toURL().text
```

Comment: So, in here we change the method behaviour for test needs. It seems to be a bit ugly but works.

Comment: as ugly as mocking in general, we mock the instance by making it behave as a real object would

Answer (score 0):

You can mock this method in test manually. 
Examle:

```
ApiConnector.metaClass.get = {endpoint -> "Return some mock data for this ${endpoint}"}
```

And if you call method get you receive the mocked value. In other way you can use some mock lib.